# xfce VNC environment no longer has control bar menus for screens (no close, or maximize panel)

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, xfce, vnc

I upgraded from 18.04.4 LTS to 20.04 and now my xfce VNC environment is broken. There are no title or command bars (Close, Maximize, Minimize) on windows any longer. Only the menu bar (File, Edit, View, etc.)

This is my `~/.vnc/xstartup`:

```
#!/bin/sh

#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &

# Fix to make GNOME and GTK stuff work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

xfce4-session &

# before Ubuntu 18.04:
# gnome-settings-daemon &

# Ubuntu 18.04 and later:
/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings &
```

And here is a screenshot of what it looks like. You can see the launcher appears to be cut thinner on the top and bottom as if a border is missing.
[image]

Comment: I'm not quiet sure, but has wayland sth to do with it? I know the gnome session starts by default with wayland, but how about xfce? VNC relies on the X-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by installing `xfwm4 4.14.5` from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/amd64/xfwm4/4.14.5-1).  It was not usable without the fix. (If the link breaks again, please try doing a Google search on "xfwm4_4.14.5-1_amd64.deb").

Comment: resolved for me too . the windows decoration was apresented. https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/xfwm4_4.14.5-1_amd64.deb.html

Comment: Thanks! finally fixed :D

Comment: Good for me to.

Comment: This link is not available now.

Comment: Here's a link to that file https://drive.google.com/file/d/15JqUIaLAEtQZ3C5Pd7-NjBO1yo0enHGD/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the known 20.04 issues mentioned in the [release notes](https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-20-04-released/).
"Window decorations are not displayed with tightvncserver. Users depending on VNC are advised to wait until 20.04.1 or use an alternative window manager for VNC until this is resolved."

Here is the bug report about it.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfwm4/+bug/1860921

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to wait for the 20.04.1 release then (as I should have done in the first place, but I was doing a data migration and wanted zfs 0.8 for encryption).

Comment: Well, we now have 20.04.1 and this is still broken.

Comment: even 20.04.2 :(

Answer (score 0):

same bad here with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, links above are dead (also links in https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/xfwm4_4.14.5-1_amd64.deb.html